# How to save excel file on server with php?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to save an excel file to a server, but what I really need is to send it as an email attachment, so I'm trying to store it in server and then to send it as an attachment. But I get an error with the browser, it says it cannot find the file path/to/file/sendExcell.php. 
Send excel php is the file that I'm launching in the browser and it's being launched if I comment `$objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__).'stats.xlsx');`
or if I change it to this other line:

```
$objWritter->save('php://output')
```

This is the code:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-Type: application/xlsx');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="stats.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__).'stats.xlsx');
print_r('ok');die; //never prints
```

I also cannot save it this way:

$objWriter->save();

It prints a white screen (removing the headers) and with the headers it prints the same error (cannot find the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe You have not permission. If you use Linux try chmod 777.

Comment: And, even if that helped, change it to something more restrictive afterwards immediately. You don't want 777 directories in a production environment, unless you do so on purpose. ;-)

Comment: For production usually use 755 or 644 permission

Answer (score 0):

```
$objWriter->save ( getcwd ().'/stats.xlsx')
```